# Whatis the standard way to manage (check and recover) a custom backgtround routine in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

Assume there is a bean `MyTask` with one method, which can throw an exception. I would like to invoke the method asynchronously (background routine), then check periodically (i.e. each minute) what is its status (in progress, completed or failed) and each time make a decision whether it should be started again or not.

```
@Component
class MyTask {
  public void execute(){
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 5  == 0){
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed");
    } else {
      // long operation
      System.out.println("Hello");
    } 
  }
}
```

Is there any standard way in `Spring Framework 5.3.7+` to manage custom background routine in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

Use [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html):

```java
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)                                 
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5)                                          
    public void execute() {
```

(The @EventListener waits until the application is ready.)

You'll need to configure the thread pool in your application.properties:

```
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size: 4
```

You can also inject the [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) to manage your other background tasks.

```java
@Autowired private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;
```